# Change the value of Dictionary based on the SelectedItem in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, textbox, listbox

My TextBox shows a property value of a class, which is changed based on the SelectedItem in ListBox. (So far, so good.) However, now I'd like to replace the value defined in Dictionary with a value which a user specified (The `key` is the SelectedItem in ListBox). This doesn't work, no matter what I do. It just throws an exception. Here is my full code:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using ChangeTextBoxBasedOnListBox.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> oc;
        ObservableCollection<Graph> graph;
        Dictionary<string, Graph> dic = new Dictionary<string, Graph>();
        ListBox lB;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            oc = new ObservableCollection<string>()
            {
                "Test_1",
                "Test_2"
            };

            graph = new ObservableCollection<Graph>()
            {
                new Graph(10),
                new Graph(100)
            };

            listBox.ItemsSource = oc;

            foreach (var test in oc.Select((k, i) => new { kvp = k, index = i }))
            {
                dic.Add(test.kvp, graph[test.index]);
            }
        }

        private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Graph dicValue = dic[(sender as ListBox).SelectedItem.ToString()];
            textBox.Text = Convert.ToString(dicValue.Step);
        }

        private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // This works, but this isn't what I want to do
            if (dic.ContainsKey("Test_1"))
                dic["Test_1"].Step = 1000;

            // What I want to do is:
            // (dic[(The current SelectedItem in ListBox)].Step  = (The value user specified)

            // This doesn't work ... throws an exception
            //if (lB.SelectedItem != null)
            //{
            //    if (dic.ContainsKey(lB.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            //    {
            //        dic[lB.SelectedItem.ToString()].Step = (sender as Graph).Step;
            //    }
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ChangeTextBoxBasedOnListBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChangeTextBoxBasedOnListBox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="238" Margin="88,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="288" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="523,82,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="textBox_TextChanged"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Model/Graph.cs**

```
namespace ChangeTextBoxBasedOnListBox.Model
{
    public class Graph
    {
        public Graph(int step) { Step = step; }

        public int Step { get; set; }
    }
}
```

... I think I just need one more step, but I cannot find the way. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a note, it is pointless to use ObservableCollection for the type of the `oc` and `graph` variables. There is nothing that would observe a collection change. They could be simple arrays.

Comment: @Clemens: I see, thank you. Maybe, next time I will make them `List<>`, instead of `ObservableCollection<>`. (It should be OK, right?)

Comment: And of course `(sender as Graph)` is always null, because sender is a TextBox.

Comment: @Clemens Oops, I didn't know that ... then, how can I get the user input in TextBox using `sender` (or any other way)?

Comment: @Clemens Oh, it makes sense, thank you. Let me correct one thing: I should have added `lB = sender as ListBox;` in `listBox_SelectionChanged()`. And, according to your suggestion, I should put this way: `if (lB.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                if (dic.ContainsKey(lB.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                {
                    dic[lB.SelectedItem.ToString()].Step = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)sender).Text);
                }
            }`. However, it still give me an exception ... Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is far too complicated. Actually, you do not need any event handlers at all.

Simply pass the Dictionary directly to the ListBox's ItemsSource and set `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` to its `Key` and `Value` properties. Thus the ListBox displays the key strings and you can directly access a Graph instance via the `SelectedValue` property of the ListBox.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedValue.Step, ElementName=listBox}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and everything works automatically with this code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    listBox.ItemsSource = new Dictionary<string, Graph>()
    {
        { "Test_1", new Graph(10) },
        { "Test_2", new Graph(100) }
    };
}
```